# Как разбить число на кратные значения между min и max?

Tags: javascript

Как разбить число на кратные значения между `min` и `max` ?

```
var interval = 6; // динамическое, меняется
var min = 212; // динамическое, меняется
var max = 641; // динамическое, меняется
```

На выводе нужно чтобы было примерно так:

```
var result = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700];
```

Как видно `min` и `max` корректируются для кратности, `min` может только в меньшую сторону, а `max` только в большую

Задача очень сложная, старался как мог расписать

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108504/discussion-on-question-by-rickes417-------).

Answer (score 4):

Решил вопрос собственными силами, js правда очень плохо знаю

Написал две функции маленьких, вроде выполняют свою задачу которая мне нужна

```js
function niceNum(localRange, round){
  let exponent = Math.floor(Math.log10(localRange));
  let fraction = localRange / Math.pow(10, exponent);
  let niceFraction;
  if(round){
    if(fraction < 1.5) niceFraction = 1;
    else if(fraction < 3) niceFraction = 2;
    else if(fraction < 7) niceFraction = 5;
    else niceFraction = 10;
  }else{
    if(fraction <= 1) niceFraction = 1;
    else if(fraction <= 2) niceFraction = 2;
    else if(fraction <= 5) niceFraction = 5;
    else niceFraction = 10;
  }
  return niceFraction * Math.pow(10, exponent);
}
function getScale(min, max){
  let maxTicks = 10;
  let tickSpacing;
  let range;
  let niceMin;
  let niceMax;
  range = niceNum(max - min, false);
  tickSpacing = niceNum(range / (maxTicks - 1), true);
  niceMin = Math.floor(min / tickSpacing) * tickSpacing;
  niceMax = Math.ceil(max / tickSpacing) * tickSpacing;
  let result = [];
  let step = niceMin;
  let interval = (niceMax - niceMin) / tickSpacing;
  for(let i=0; i<=interval; i++){
    result.push(parseFloat(step.toFixed(8)));
    step = step + tickSpacing;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(getScale(212, 641));
console.log(getScale(5497, 9562));
console.log(getScale(.02317, .0421));
```

Comment: У себя в рабочем коде также `maxTicks` передавал в функцию, точнее интервала